How can I make wireshark focus on only packets being sent to a website and any responses?
I have captured a few TLS handshakes, I would like to focus on one tls handshake and the communication thereafter. For example, I connect to www.facebook.com and www.pinterest.com how do I tell wireshark to focus on only packets sent between pinterest and my computer and to ignore any requests my computer has made to facebook and vice versa.

Use the filter feature.

If the traffic uses TLS, then you're not going to be able to decrypt it.
But you can still see the (encrypted) traffic by applying the filter:
ip.addr==192.0.2.1

or whatever the address of the site you're interested in is.
If you have cleartext traffic, you can also select analyze/follow/http from the menu to see the http conversation.
